# Calculating the rolling sums in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that contains information on the daily sales and daily clicks. Before I want to run my analysis, I want to aggregate the data. To make myself clearer, I will try to explain it on an example dataframe

```
item_id date          Price  Sale   Click   Discount_code     
2       01.03.2019    10       1     10      NULL
2       01.03.2019    8        1     10      Yes
2       02.03.2019    10       0     4       NULL
2       03.03.2019    10       0     6       NULL
2       04.03.2019    6        0     15      NULL 
2       05.03.2019    6        0     14      NULL
2       06.03.2019    5        0     7       NULL 
2       07.03.2019    5        1     11      NULL
2       07.03.2019    5        1     11      NULL
2       08.03.2019    5        0     9       NULL
```

If there are two sales for the given day, I have two observations for that particular day. I want to convert my dataframe to the following one by collapsing observations by item_id and price:

```
item_id    Price  CSale  Discount_code Cclicks   firstdate   lastdate  
2           10       1      No             20    01.03.2019 03.03.2019
2           8        1      Yes            10    01.03.2019 01.03.2019
2           6        0      NULL           29    04.03.2019 05.03.2019
2           5        2      NULL           38    06.03.2019 08.03.2019
```

Where CSale correponds to the cumulative sales for the given price and given item_id, Cclicks corresponds to the cumulative clicks for the given price and given item_id, firstdate is the first date on which the given item was available for the given price and lastdate is the last date on which the given item was available for the given price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the problem, OP wants to [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg) the DataFrame on the basis of `item_id` and `Price`.

```
# Creating the DataFrames
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, sum, min, max, first
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(2,'01.03.2019',10,1,10,None),(2,'01.03.2019',8,1,10,'Yes'),
                                 (2,'02.03.2019',10,0,4,None),(2,'03.03.2019',10,0,6,None),
                                 (2,'04.03.2019',6,0,15,None),(2,'05.03.2019',6,0,14,None),
                                 (2,'06.03.2019',5,0,7,None),(2,'07.03.2019',5,1,11,None),
                                 (2,'07.03.2019',5,1,11,None),(2,'08.03.2019',5,0,9,None)],
                                ('item_id','date','Price','Sale','Click','Discount_code'))
# Converting string column date to proper date
df = df.withColumn('date',to_date(col('date'),'dd.MM.yyyy'))
df.show()
+-------+----------+-----+----+-----+-------------+
|item_id|      date|Price|Sale|Click|Discount_code|
+-------+----------+-----+----+-----+-------------+
|      2|2019-03-01|   10|   1|   10|         null|
|      2|2019-03-01|    8|   1|   10|          Yes|
|      2|2019-03-02|   10|   0|    4|         null|
|      2|2019-03-03|   10|   0|    6|         null|
|      2|2019-03-04|    6|   0|   15|         null|
|      2|2019-03-05|    6|   0|   14|         null|
|      2|2019-03-06|    5|   0|    7|         null|
|      2|2019-03-07|    5|   1|   11|         null|
|      2|2019-03-07|    5|   1|   11|         null|
|      2|2019-03-08|    5|   0|    9|         null|
+-------+----------+-----+----+-----+-------------+
```

As can be seen in the printSchema below that the dataframe's `date` column is in `date` format.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- item_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Price: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Sale: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Click: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Discount_code: string (nullable = true)
```

Finally aggregating `agg()` the columns below. Just a caveat - Since `Discount_code` is a `string` column and we need to aggregate it as well, we will take the [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) non-Null value while grouping.

```
df = df.groupBy('item_id','Price').agg(sum('Sale').alias('CSale'),
                                       first('Discount_code',ignorenulls = True).alias('Discount_code'),
                                       sum('Click').alias('Cclicks'),
                                       min('date').alias('firstdate'),
                                       max('date').alias('lastdate'))
df.show()
+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------+----------+----------+
|item_id|Price|CSale|Discount_code|Cclicks| firstdate|  lastdate|
+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------+----------+----------+
|      2|    6|    0|         null|     29|2019-03-04|2019-03-05|
|      2|    5|    2|         null|     38|2019-03-06|2019-03-08|
|      2|    8|    1|          Yes|     10|2019-03-01|2019-03-01|
|      2|   10|    1|         null|     20|2019-03-01|2019-03-03|
+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------+----------+----------+
```